# notification_receive Event on firebase console android

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending notifications to almost 24000 users. But on the Firebase console, it's showing only around 10,000 counts next to the notification_receive event. Why this count is very low is this count accurate?

Answer (score 0):

Don't sweat it my friend. It is because remaining users haven't had Internet connection or some other problems to receive your notification.
you can test this by sending a test notification to yourself while your internet is off. then track your Firebase Console when you become Online you will receive it and console updates

Comment: Thank you. So notification_receive when the application is in the background. what if the application is not in the background nor in the foreground? how to get a count of the total users who received the notification?

Comment: it is Firebase console duty. there is not any other ways.

Comment: Okay thanks for help...